# what does tail + number does? What about head

Tags: shell, ls, tcsh, tail

I just called this command `ls -l | tail +3`. Firstly,  ls -s, produces 3 lines, adding piping strips first line and then prints each file names on a separate line. How does it do that? It doesn't make sense.

Also, I thought tail filename displays last 10 lines. How does `+`  (and minus) plays into this equation?

Same thing about head? How does it work?

Comment: What does your `man` page say?  When you type `man tail`, what response do you get?  What part of that do you need help understanding?

Answer (score 8):

From the `tail` [man page](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/tail.1.html):

> The **tail** utility displays the contents of *file* or, by default, its standard input, to the standard output.
>
> The display begins at a byte, line or 512-byte block location in the input.  Numbers having a leading plus ("+") sign are relative to the beginning of the input, for example, "-c +2" starts the display at the second byte of the input.  Numbers having a leading minus ("-") sign or no explicit sign are relative to the end of the input, for example, "-n 2" displays the last two lines of the input.  The default starting location is "-n 10", or the last 10 lines of the input.

So in your case, `tail +3` (the `-n` is implied) means start at the 3rd line of the input (`ls -l`) and print the rest.  For example:

`ls -l` output:

```
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 carl  staff  0 Oct 28 13:18 file1
-rw-r--r--  1 carl  staff  0 Oct 28 13:18 file2
-rw-r--r--  1 carl  staff  0 Oct 28 13:18 file3
-rw-r--r--  1 carl  staff  0 Oct 28 13:18 file4
-rw-r--r--  1 carl  staff  0 Oct 28 13:18 file5
-rw-r--r--  1 carl  staff  0 Oct 28 13:18 file6
```

`ls -l | tail +3` output:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 carl  staff  0 Oct 28 13:18 file2
-rw-r--r--  1 carl  staff  0 Oct 28 13:18 file3
-rw-r--r--  1 carl  staff  0 Oct 28 13:18 file4
-rw-r--r--  1 carl  staff  0 Oct 28 13:18 file5
-rw-r--r--  1 carl  staff  0 Oct 28 13:18 file6
```

Same output, just with the first couple of lines stripped off.

Answer (score 4):

From the manpage:

> If the first character of N (the number of bytes or lines)  is  a  `+',
>          print  beginning  with the Nth item from the start of each file, other-
>          wise, print the last N items in the file.  N may have a multiplier suf-
>          fix: b 512, k 1024, m 1024*1024.

Comment: Beaten by Carl, but liked the formulation in my man page better, so leaving it as is.

Answer (score 2):

Answering:

> Firstly, ls -s, produces 3 lines, adding piping strips first line and then prints each file names on a separate line. How does it do that? It doesn't make sense.

The answer is that the `ls` commands looks at its standard output and checks whether it is connected to a tty.  If it is, then it formats for display purposes.  If it is not (for example, the output is a file or pipe), then it prints one entry per line.

- The option '`-C`' forces multi-column output (as if going to a terminal).
- The option '`-1`' forces single-column output (as if going to a pipe).